# my Rect stays for 1 frame created in 'for in' loop Pygame

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

The problem lies in the algorithm instead of Pygame. 'rows' is an array of pygame.rect()s. the rect created in the last line only stays for 1 frame. how would i go about fixing this problem?

sorry if its a shit question, i'm gracious for the help

```
for row in rows:
      moupos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      mouclick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
      if mouclick[0] == 1 and row.collidepoint(moupos):
          row = pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,row)
```

Comment: Normally, if you want something to stay for more then one frame you need to draw it every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow keep track of which rect you already clicked.

There are of course endless ways to do this. One way is to use a custom class instead of a simple `Rect` so we can easily keep track of the state of each "row".

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame

class Row:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.clicked = False

def main():
    pygame.init()
    quit = False
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((230, 230))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    rows = [
        Row(pygame.Rect(10, 10, 100, 100)),
        Row(pygame.Rect(10, 120, 100, 100)),
        Row(pygame.Rect(120, 10, 100, 100)),
        Row(pygame.Rect(120, 120, 100, 100))
    ]

    while not quit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return 
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for row in (row for row in rows if row.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)):
                    row.clicked = True

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey12'))
        moupos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for row in rows:
            if row.clicked:
                color = pygame.Color('orange')
            else:
                color = pygame.Color('green') if row.rect.collidepoint(moupos) else pygame.Color('dodgerblue')
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, row.rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]